# How to block Facebook in-page popup notifications in lower left corner?

Tags: facebook, facebook-notifications

Facebook is displaying annoying pop ups within the browser page - see the following screenshot, lower left corner:

[image]

How do I stop these? I have blocked Facebook notifications in Chrome, so I guess this is not this kind of notification. This is probably directly in the Facebook html page, right? So probably the solution lies somewhere in the Facebook setting?

Note that I don't want to disable these notifications completely, I want to have them available in the notifications "mailbox".

I tried to go to https://www.facebook.com/settings?tab=notifications but I don't see any corresponding setting there:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The F.B. Purity extension can do this: https://www.fbpurity.com/install.htm

The setting is under FBP->Notification Options->check "Hide Notification Popups"